# InfoPath 2010 - A formatting rule will only let me type a number not a word

Tags: infopath

I've added a formatting rule to hide a section based on a drop down list where the drop down selection is equal to "No" but it will only let me type a number not text. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Are the drop down field properties true/false or 1/0, it might be looking for a 1 or 0.

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to put two different formatting options in one rule. I separated them into two different rules and it worked like a charm.